# exclude a logic for some items in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array and i want to exclude the application of some logic for one element in array:

```js
arr.map(key => {
  return {
    uno: key
      .map(text => {
        return text.toUppercase
      })
      .join(' / '),
    key: key,
    ...test(
      key,
      uno,
      do,
    ),
  };
})
```

How to apply this part:

```
...test(
   key,
   uno,
   do,
     ),
```

only for these `key` that are not equall with `test`? something like this: key !== 'test' .  How to solve this?

Comment: hard to read need editing

Comment: please add the source data and the wanted result. - and btw, what you have tried. (`do` is a reserved word in javascript)

Comment: error: *"message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'do'"*

Comment: toUppercase is in wrong case, try map(t => t.toUpperCase())

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to filter `arr` before you use map() AFAIK you cant "skip" in `$.map()`

```
arr.filter(key => key != 'test').map(...
```

Comment: if i will use `arr.filter()` i will filter the array from start, but i want to filter only starting from `...test(
   key,
   uno,
   do,
     ),`. I mean, i want to apply for all element from array besides for the `key === 'test'` It is possible to do this?